# Exiting a defined function when a requirement is met

Tags: python, algorithm, function, primes

I am trying to generate primes as quickly as possible, going through multiple versions of code and comparing the speeds of each version as I go. I have moved onto a version that uses the Sieve of Sundaram. There a lot of explanations of what this is online, so I'm not really going to explain it. Basically, it marks off numbers that couldn't be primes, and then the remaining numbers get multiplied by 2 and add one, and then those numbers are all going to be primes. It is fairly simple to implement in code. The function takes some number n, and finds all of the primes less than or equal to n. However, instead of it doing this, I need it to find the first n primes. There is a theorem that says that the nth prime will always be less than 2^n. However, using this function to find large numbers of primes would be extremely unrealistic because I would have to search up to 2^n. I am trying to find a way to check `len(prime_list) == n`, and then break from the function then and just `return overall_time, prime_list` (the prime_list isn't really required for what I am trying to do, but it doesn't affect the program). Here is how I currently have the function defined:

```
def SieveOfSundaram(n):
    prime_list = [2]
    nNew = int((n - 1) / 2)
    marked = [0] * nNew
    start_time = time.perf_counter_ns()
    for i in range(1, (nNew + 1)):
        j = i
        while (i + j + (2 * i * j)) <= nNew:
            marked[i + j + (2 * i * j)] = 1
            j += 1

    for i in range(1, nNew + 1):
        if marked[i] == 0:
            prime_list.append((2 * i + 1))
    end_time = time.perf_counter_ns()
    overall_time = end_time - start_time

    return prime_list, overall_time
```

I have tried rewriting the code to instead of defining a list at the beginning of length nNew, to instead adding a new element to the list at each iteration in the first for loop. However, I couldn't get this to work because you need to mark off all elements before you can determine the primes, so you can't just check if it is a prime without doing all of the computations every time, and since the intent is for it to be quick (current best time I have is 0.0616s for 5000 primes), doing that would defeat the entire purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Just use an ordinary `if` statement: `if len(prime_list) == n: return prime_list, overall_time`

Comment: The theorem that says that the nth prime is less than 2^n is certainly true, and utterly useless. For example, it claims that the 25th prime (97) is less than 2^25 (33,554,432). True, but useless. You can get a much tighter upper bound from [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Table_of_π(x),_x_/_log_x,_and_li(x)). For example, if you want to find the 5000th prime, an upper bound of 100000 is more than adequate (whereas the theorem's upper bound of 2^5000 is absurd).

Comment: @user3386109 I realized this, and have been trying to find a way to calculate pi(x) so that I could directly calculate just the 5000th prime. However, I don't want to import this value because that feels like cheating. I have tried to find an implementation of the Meissel-Lehmer algorithm, but I can't find one and am struggling to understand the math behind it.  My solution to the problem that I have is to calculate the 5000th prime, and then use that as my range.

Answer (score 1):

A standard solution is to just do reasonably sized blocks that won't overshoot by too much. For example blocks sized at `10*sqrt(n)` will let you do `O(sqrt(n) log(n))` checks and overshoot with `O(sqrt(n))` work. Which is a lot better than `O(n)` checks.

However for this, you're probably overthinking. The following almost unoptimized approach takes about 0.01 s for the first 5000 primes.

```
def primes ():
    yield 2
    yield 3
    f = {}
    n = 5
    for p in primes():
        if p == 2:
            continue
        p2 = p*p
        while n < p2:
            if n in f:
                double_p = f.pop(n)
                m = n + double_p
                while m in f:
                    m += double_p
                f[m] = double_p
            else:
                yield n
            n += 2
        f[n] = 2*p

def n_primes (n):
    p_list = []
    for p in primes():
        p_list.append(p)
        if n <= len(p_list):
            return p_list

import time
count = 0
s = 0
start_time = time.perf_counter_ns()
prime_list = n_primes(5000)
end_time = time.perf_counter_ns()
print(s, (end_time - start_time) / 10**9)
```